# How can I use image background css property in table mailers?

Tags: html, html-table, html-email

How to use a background image in table based email template, which should support the image background property on all devices and email clients?

Comment: Please tell us what you've already tried.

Answer (score 0):

you can write background images as inline css for table.

```
    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="20" background="background_image.png">
      <tr>
    <td>
   <p>Content on a pretty background image.</p>
  </td>
 </tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: background="background_image.png" Don't works in Microsoft Outlook if rendering an e-mail template Signature